# Apache Camel: How I get message returned from Rest API?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a route with an error handler:

```
<route errorHandlerRef="magentoCustomerErrorHandler" id="customers.route2">
  ...
  <to id="_to1" uri="http4://{{magento.api.url}}customer/"/>
</route>
```

And in my error handler, I call a processor in onRedelivery

```
<bean class="br.com.company.ProcessorError" id="myErrorProcessor"/>
<bean class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder" id="magentoCustomerErrorHandler">
    <property name="deadLetterUri" value="activemq:magento:customers:DQL"/>
    <property name="onRedelivery" ref="myErrorProcessor"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
</bean>
```

In the error processor, I try to get the message returned by the API but I only get the message generated by the camel.

**ErrorProcessor class:**

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Exception cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("FailedBecause", cause.getMessage());
}
```

**API Response:**

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Token doesn't exist or is expired."}]}}
```

**Expected Message:**

```
Token doesn't exist or is expired
```

**Returned message:**

```
HTTP operation failed invoking http://myurl.com/api/rest/customer/ with statusCode: 500
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error here is the type of the Exception that I used.

To I get the body returned by the REST, I need to use the HttpOperationFailedException.

**ErrorProcessor class**

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    HttpOperationFailedException cause = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, HttpOperationFailedException.class);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("FailedBecause", cause.getMessage());
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("ResponseBody", cause.getResponseBody());
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the `useOriginalMessage` option :

```
<bean class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder" id="magentoCustomerErrorHandler">
<property name="deadLetterUri" value="activemq:magento:customers:DQL"/>
<property name="onRedelivery" ref="myErrorProcessor"/>
<property name="useOriginalMessage" value="true"/>
<property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="myRedeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
```

Comment: This does not work. I want to get the request body. For me, useOriginalMessage, don't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Camel treats any HTTP response code other than 200 as a failure when making http calls, so you need to `setThrowExceptionOnFailure` to false to instruct camel route to ignore http response code and just return whatever body it receives.

Here is the Java DSL example:

```
getContext().getEndpoint(endpoint, HttpEndpoint.class).setThrowExceptionOnFailure(false);
```

Make sure the endpoint is the host:port only without any http path, it does a exact match.

Refer to: http://camel.apache.org/http.html, look for `throwExceptionOnFailure`

Please note, if you set it to false, then camel won't go to exception handling route, it returns as normal, and you need to handle the error response outside the camel route. I think this way is better because you have full response from the service you are calling, and you can do your error handling based on the actual failure code/reason from the response.

Comment: Thank you, good point. But in this moment, I need only to get the response body and append it to the original body for any response code != 200. Them I think that use setThrowExceptionOnFailure is not a good way for me.

Comment: The thing is, if you don't set throwExceptionOnFailure to false then Camel would only look at the HTTP response code and wrap the actual response body somewhere in Camel exception. I have found the easiest way is to tell Camel to return whatever Camel has received, you can keep request body somewhere so you can append the response to request, or use .enrich() instead of .to(), then you can implement your own aggregator.